# Tree shaking does not work in vite library mode

Tags: vite, tree-shaking

I am building a library with [vite library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode), the problem is the bundler is not tree shakable.

There are some related topics [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5174), [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8237) and maybe [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2860) also.

So, anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this has to do with the way `esbuild` bundles under the hood. It's a little different than the way `babel` has done it with their more established plugin eco-system.

Some of your code that you would expect to the `tree-shaken` by default might not be marked as `/* @__PURE__ */` as you might expect.

- [esbuild issue](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1883)
- [esbuild docs](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#pure)

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Mark all functions that are able to be dropped if unused, tree-shaken, with /* @**PURE** */. (use caution)

```
// src/icon.tsx

/* @__PURE__ */
export const Icon = React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement, IconProps>(
  (props, forwardedRef) => (
    <svg {...props} ref={forwardedRef}>
      <path
        d="M14.5"
        fill={props.color}
      />
    </svg>
  ),
)
```

2. Preserve modules in your build step:

```
// vite.config.ts

rollupOptions: {
  output: {
    preserveModules: true,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem building my library with Vite lib mode ..

Either, @hoop71 solution works but you have to mark everything with `/* @__PURE__ */` or use [rollup-plugin-pure](https://github.com/danielroe/rollup-plugin-pure) to help with that.

Either, don't use lib mode and use rollup like I did :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import pkg from "./package.json";
import { visualizer } from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";

export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    minifyIdentifiers: false,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      preserveEntrySignatures: "strict",
      input: ["src/index.ts", "src/nav/index.ts"],
      external: [...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies)],
      output: [
        {
          dir: "dist",
          format: "esm",
          preserveModules: true,
          preserveModulesRoot: "src",
          entryFileNames: ({ name: fileName }) => {
            return `${fileName}.js`;
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxRuntime: "classic",
    }),
    visualizer(),
    dts(),
  ],
});
```

⚠️ `jsxRuntime : "classic"`  is removed from `@vitejs/plugin-react@4.0.0`...
I have not upgrade it to v4 yet and handle automatic runtime. [Read more](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/releases/tag/plugin-react%404.0.0)